# Create a custom Wordpress form

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to create an events form using wordpress plugin
the form should have the following
image - text box - google maps - tags - date time fields (user can insert multiple dates and times)

like the attached form

Is there any free plugin to create this form?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/RLQp6.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try these plugins.

[`http://wordpress.org/plugins/event-registration/`](http://wordpress.org/plugins/event-registration/).
[`http://wordpress.org/plugins/visual-form-builder/`](http://wordpress.org/plugins/visual-form-builder/).
[`https://wordpress.org/plugins/form-maker/`](https://wordpress.org/plugins/form-maker/).

Or you can use your own custom form plugin. Using your own codes. You can use `shortcodes`. See the [`CODEX`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Writing_a_Plugin) for more information.

If you need my help. Please find me any of social network by searching `yeshansachithak`.